# Arrays of char pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

Here's a function prototype:

```
void foobar(char* array[]);
```

But how would I call this function, and with what arguments? Could someone give me a simple example?

Comment: the input should be a pointer to char pointer

Comment: Depends.. what do you want it to do...?!?!

Comment: A pointer to a pointer just scares me...

Answer (score 7):

Quoting from [c-faq](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html) (as array name conversion rule to pointers is same in C and C++ both):

> Since arrays decay immediately into pointers, an array is never actually passed to a function. You can pretend that a function receives an array as a parameter, and illustrate it by declaring the corresponding parameter as an array:
>
> ```
> void f(char a[])
> { ... }
> ```
>
> Interpreted literally, this declaration would have no use, so the compiler turns around and pretends that you'd written a pointer declaration, since that's what the function will in fact receive:
>
> ```
> void f(char *a)
> { ... }
> ```

Therefore

```
void foobar(char* array[]);
```

is equivalent to

```
void foobar(char** array);
```

You need to pass an argumant of type `char **` to this function.

Comment: Which can, of course, come from an implicit conversion of a `char* arr[]`.

Comment: Could someone give me a simple example - I mean actual code? Using string literals perhaps? Or is this just wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply and comments. Here is what I came up with and it seems to work. Not quite sure why it does, though. Could someone confirm that this is indeed 'correct' code:

```
void foobar(char* array[]);

void main() {

    char* t[3];
    t[0] = "first";
    t[1] = "second";
    t[2] = "third";
    foobar(t);
}

void foobar(char* array[]) {

    cout << *(array + 0) << endl;
    cout << *(array + 1) << endl;
    cout << *(array + 2) << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
first
second
third
```

Comment: It looks almost correct to me, but you should change the parameter to `const char *const []` if your function won't modify it. And t should be `const char *t[3]` if it points to string literals.